# Display Student Record in Unix

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

Write a command or logic , which will read the contents from the given input file and fetch the Students of School named as Sangamithra.

Input File format: The sequence of columns in the input file(input.txt ) is as below, columns separated by "|"(excluding the double quotes).

StudentName|Class|SchoolName

The sequence of Column in the output is as below, columns separated by "|"(excluding the double quotes) ,

SchoolName|Class|StudentName

Example:
suppose `input.txt`

```
Deepu|First|Meridian

Neethu|Second|Meridian

Sethu|First|DAV

Theekshana|Second|DAV

Teju|First|Sangamithra
```

And Output :

```
Sangamithra|First|Teju
```

Comment: You question is a little confusing. It looks like the input is in the format "name|first or second|school". It seems like 'DAV' is used as a school in your input, but as a name in your output.

Comment: "Sangamithra" only appears in the last line so how would the second part of the output apply?

Comment: Yeah, that second line isn't in the input extract given to us. I'm assuming we were only given part of the input for brevity. Regardless, my answer should be plenty to work it out from if it isn't correct.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [Processing tables : homework](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/501902)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '/Sangamithra/ {print $3 "|" $2 "|" $1}' input.txt
Sangamithra|First|Teju
```

(Please note that your second line in the desired output doesn't appear anywhere in the input file)

**Explanation**

The `-F` flag means that awk sees the `|` in this case as the field seperator.

The `/Sangamithra/` section means that only input lines containing that pattern will be in the output.

the `{print $3 "|" $2 "|" $1}` section is the main script. This prints out the third, second, and first fields of the input (in that order), seperated by `|` symbols.

Comment: Setting `OFS="|"` would make it cleaner (`print $3, $2, $1`).

Comment: Honestly, I'm struggling to get it working @Kusalananda `awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '/Sangamithra/ {print $3 $2 $1}' input.txt` outputs the correct result with no output field seperator. And `awk -F'|' '/Sangamithra/ {print $3 $2 $1} OFS="|"' input.txt` outputs the correct result but echos the whole file first.

Comment: I know probably nobody will see this answer, but I've already learned a lot about awk.

Comment: Using commas between the arguments to `print` (as I did in my comment above) would insert the value of `OFS` between the fields. With no commas, you are just concatenating the data into one field.