# Awk script to extract lines whose average of two columns are greater than a particular number

Tags: awk

I'm writing the logic / commands, which will read the contents from the given input file and display the records of students, whose average of "two subject marks" is more than 90.

Input.txt file -

```
Deepu#First#Meridian#95#90
Neethu#Second#Meridian#80#75
Sethu#First#DAV#75#70
Theekshana#Second#DAV#80#79
Teju#First#Sangamithra#88#63
Theekshitha#Second#Sangamithra#91#90
```

output:

```
Deepu|First|Meridian|95|90|92.5
```

I wrote the following command-

```
 $ awk -F'#' ' { if(($4+$5)/2 >90) {print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" ($4+$5)/2 }} input.txt .
```

It is showing error : `F# not found`.

Comment: This task could be solved with an `awk` script and defining the correct input field separator. Or if it should be a pure shell script, you might get some help in the [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ)

Comment: Please, at least write what issues you have instead of just copying the homework assignment.

Comment: @Kusalananda It is not a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/501995/display-student-record-in-unix, it only uses similar sample data. Here the task is to print lines that fulfill an arithmetic condition based on their fields. The other task was to rearrange the fields.

Comment: An order is not, of course, a question.

Comment: @Kusalananda here the thing is I am writing a command given below-  $ awk -F'#' ' { if(($4+$5)/2 >90) {print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" ($4+$5)/2 }} input.txt                   . it is showing error : F# not found. can you please help me out now at least!!

Comment: @chinmayavijay Now _that_ is a good question to ask! Please add that to the actual question.

Comment: never using this site again.no filter for users.

Comment: @Kusalananda I did. Help me out,please.

Comment: @chinmayavijay Welcome to the U&L SE. The folks here like to see some prior effort to be put in to questions, since they have to spend their own time writing answers. You have closed that gap now with your attempt to use `awk`, so +1 from me.

Comment: @chinmayavijay Thanks for updating the question with what you have already tried. I added an answer explaining what's wrong with your code and also giving a few alternative ways of doing this with `awk`.  Feel free to comment on the answer if there's anything unclear.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your command:

```
awk -F'#' ' { if(($4+$5)/2 >90) {print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" ($4+$5)/2 }} input.txt
```

You are missing a single quote at the end of the `awk` code.  It should look something like

```
awk -F'#' ' { if(($4+$5)/2 >90) {print $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $4 "|" $5 "|" ($4+$5)/2 }}' input.txt
```

Also, one would probably write the `awk` code as

```
awk -F '#' -v OFS='|' '($4+$5)/2 > 90 { $(NF+1) = ($4+$5)/2; print }' input.txt
```

This uses `OFS` to automatically delimit the output fields by `|`, and also just adds the average as a new field at the end of the current record before outputting it (assigning to `$(NF+1)` adds a new field; `NF` is the number of fields in the current record and `$NF` is the last field). This way, we don't have to mention each field that we want to output.

An alternative `awk` solution:

```
awk -F '#' -v OFS='|' '($(NF+1) = ($4+$5)/2) > 90' input.txt
```

This sets the new last field to the average of the 4th and 5th fields and prints the record if that new field is greater than 90. This avoids calculating the average twice and it relies on `print` being the *default action* if a condition like this is true.